# Trouble using a function to calculate error rate for machine learning (Adaboost)

Tags: adaboost

---

Hi, I am trying to calculate the error rate of an Adaboost model and I am confused as to how to use the error rate function.

Here is the function I am trying to use:
[image]

And here is the data table I am calculating the error for:
[image]

So, I assume you do:

1/8(0.35)(????) + 1/8(.2)(????) + 1/8(.1)(????) + 1/8(.05)(????) ..... and so on until you add all 8 of them up. My problem is that I do not know what to put in the equation AFTER the w sub j. Can anyone help me figure out what the  sigma(C(x) != y) means and what numbers to plugin there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

late response...

$$ \delta(c(x) != y) $$ means if the label of x labelled by classifier x not correct(not equals to target y), then it output 1, otherwise output 0.

delta(something) means if something is true, then output 1, if something is false, then output 0.